# Maximum file name size in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am having a question about the maximum size of file name in hdfs and maximum size of path to files in hdfs( how deeply file structure can be nested).

I have written a Map-Reduce job and I am producing the customized name for files produce by Reducer in output. So just need to know the maximum size of file name and maximum depth of the directory structure so that i can make sure in my code that I do not exceed the maximum possible size.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the filesystem operating system has under it.

Example: For the ext FS (currently the most used on Linux):

```
max filename length: 255 bytes
max path length: none
```

The extension is not something the FS is aware of, it 255 bytes, extension included (you can have file names without any extensions).

Comment: when i will be running my Map Reduce job file system would be by default HDFS ( hadoop distributed file system ) . So my question was specific to HDFS.

Comment: This is what I was trying to explain. It totally depends on operating system. So if you are using UNIX OS then your HDFS will inherit the filename convention standards from UNIX only.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a single universal limit for HDFS file name length. It depends on configuration.

Per [HDFS-6055](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6055), by default, the limit is 255.